# View gzipped file content in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How can I decompress and view few lines of a compressed file in hdfs.
The below command displays the last few lines of the compressed data

```
hadoop fs -tail /myfolder/part-r-00024.gz
```

Is there a way I can use the -text command and pipe the output to tail command? I tried this but this doesn't work.

```
hadoop fs -text /myfolder/part-r-00024.gz > hadoop fs -tail /myfolder/
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following will show you the specified number of lines without decompressing the whole file:

```
hadoop fs -cat /hdfs_location/part-00000.gz | zcat | head -n 20
```

The following will page the file, also without first decompressing the whole of it:

```
hadoop fs -cat /hdfs_location/part-00000.gz | zmore
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following, should work as long as your file isn't too big (since the whole thing will be decompressed):

```
hadoop fs -text /myfolder/part-r-00024.gz | tail
```

Comment: I've tried that.That  created a file called tail on my local machine which was about 9 GB in size. My server is a Windows 2008 server using  hadoop MapR client not a linux server.

Comment: Then you'll have to run a hadoop job which decompresses the data to HDFS, and then tail the decompressed file, I think.

Comment: Ok,I ended up writing a pig script to view the content. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a pig script.

```
A = LOAD '/myfolder/part-r-00024.gz' USING PigStorage('\t');
B = LIMIT A 10;
DUMP B;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gunzip to view the compressed file contents:

```
 hdfs dfs -cat /path/filename.gz | gunzip
```